# MySQL recursive relationship prevents me from doing inserts

Tags: mysql, database-design

I am getting this error because I try to INSERT into a table but the foreign key has no other entries to refer to because I am trying to make a recursive relationship in MySQL workbench. It looks like this:

[image]

It is a relationship between the user table and the message table.

A message entry needs to have a `from_id` and a `to_id` to be able to know who sent to who. That is fine. But then I needed a recursive relationship on the message table where a message could be a reply to another message, but it does not have to be a reply because the first message can never be a reply to another message because it is the first message. So When I try to insert into this table I get this error:

```
#1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`message`, CONSTRAINT `fk_message_message1` FOREIGN KEY (`reply_to`) REFERENCES `message` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
```

Here is the message table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `message` (
  `id`              INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT '',
  `message` TEXT    NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  `reply_to`        INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '1' COMMENT '',
  `from_id`         INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  `to_id`           INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  `is_active`       INT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1' COMMENT '',
  `sent_time`       INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  `is_viewed`       INT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)  COMMENT '',
  INDEX `from_id` (`from_id` ASC)  COMMENT '',
  INDEX `to_id` (`to_id` ASC)  COMMENT '',
  INDEX `sent_time` (`sent_time` ASC)  COMMENT '',
  INDEX `reply_to` (`reply_to` ASC)  COMMENT '',
  CONSTRAINT `fk_message_user1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`from_id`)
    REFERENCES `user` (`id`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_message_user2`
    FOREIGN KEY (`to_id`)
    REFERENCES `user` (`id`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_message_message1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`reply_to`)
    REFERENCES `message` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8
```

Now I know what the problem is, but I do not have a solution. I want to be able to model the db like showed in the picture with recursive relationship. So that others can see the recursive relationship and understand that it exists. But When I synchronize on Mysql workbench then the constraint gets added to the database and now I can not do inserts on the message table.

How should I solve this?

Comment: Can you drop the constraint?

Comment: Can I have a recursive relationship without constraint? How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change definition of `reply_to` to a column which can have `NULL` value:

```
reply_to INT(11) UNSIGNED,
```

And insert `NULL` into `reply_to`, when message is first (not reply to another message).

Sample on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c5055/1)